# Normalization of image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have RGB image of size (2048X3072X3) with uint8 class and I want to normalize the Green and Red channel of the RGB image. I wrote following code:

```
      Image_rgb=imread('RGB.jpg');   %Reading RGB image
      Image_red = Image_rgb(:,:,1);   %Reading R channel of  image
      Image_green = Image_rgb(:,:,2); %Reading G channel of  image
      x = double(Image_green(:));  
      m = mean(x);  
      s = std(x);
      x = (x - m) / s;   % normalization of green channel
```

But after normalization the image x is of dimension 6291456x1 rather then 2048X3072.

Can anybody please tell me how can I get normalize image with  2048X3072 dimension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
  x = double(Image_green);  
  m = mean(x(:));  
  s = std(x(:));
  x = (x - m) / s;   % normalization of green channel
```

Comment: Great!  Can you flag this as the answer?